# How to insert data to a new table based on condtion using INTO CLAUSE?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012. I am new to T-SQL.

I have a table called `tblEmp` where phone no of some employee is NULL.

I want to copy all these data to a new table using `INTO` clause, but in the new table it should replace all the NULL phone nos with a string 'NA'

I think this can be done by `CASE` statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [ISNULL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) statement

Query:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
SELECT isnull(phone_no, 'NA')  AS phone_no,
       name,
       .....
FROM tblEmp
```

OR [SELECT-INTO](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx) Statment:

```
SELECT isnull(phone_no, 'NA') AS phone_no,
       name,
       .....
INTO newtable
FROM tblEmp
```

**[ExampleSqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/083ae/1)**

Comment: I want to copy all these data to a new table using INTO clause

Comment: and what problem you see in my query? you want just copy rows where phone no is null?

Comment: Yes you are correct.But I was struggling when i tried with INTO CLAUSE.so need the query for that

Comment: Your second answer showing an error ** An object or column name is missing or empty. For SELECT INTO statements, verify each column has a name. For other statements, look for empty alias names. Aliases defined as "" or [] are not allowed. Change the alias to a valid name.  **

Comment: @DeepakKumarPadhy ok try now with `AS phone_no`

Answer (score 3):

```
INSERT INTO NewTable(col1,col2,....)
SELECT case when phone_no is null then 'NA' else phone_no end,
   name,....
FROM tblEmp
```

Answer (score 0):

A little simpler (no need to explicitly state all column names), but in two steps:

```
select * into newTable from tblEmp
update newTable set phoneNo = 'NA' where phoneNo is null
```

Might not be exactly what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Use COALESCE (http://sqlzoo.net/wiki/COALESCE).

> COALESCE takes any number of arguments and returns the first value
>   that is not null.
>   COALESCE(x,y,z) = x if x is not NULL
>   COALESCE(x,y,z) = y if x is NULL and y is not NULL
>   COALESCE(x,y,z) = z if x and y are NULL but z is not NULL

```
INSERT INTO tblEmp2(Column1, Column2, ...)
SELECT (COALESCE(tblEmp.phone, 'NA'), ...)
FROM tblEmp
```